# Verlinde formula, moduli space vector bundle on genus 2,3 curves.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

I'd like to prove "by hands" the Verlinde formula for moduli space of rank two semistable vector bundles with fixed determinant on a curve of genus two and three.
For a curve of genus two and even degree I proved that this moduli space is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^3$, using GIT techniques, so it's ok! For the odd case I know that this space is isomorphic to the intersection of two quadric in $\mathbb{P}^5$. For what concerne the proof I saw the Newstead's article. Does a modern proof of this statement exist?
Furthermore, could you give me a suggestion about how to proceed the genus three case? I studied the singularity and went on with three blow up for the even case following the work of Kiem. How can I say in this way something about the cohomology of this space?